# $A^TPA-P$ is negative definite, does it imply that $APA^T-P$ is negative definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra, positive-definite, lyapunov-functions

If $P$ is positive definite, and if $A^TPA-P$ is negative definite, does it imply that $APA^T-P$ is negative definite?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: Any conditions on A? Otherwise you can just pick P to be the unit matrix and A to be triangular to get a counterexample

Comment: The condition on A is that its eigenvalues are in the unit circle.

Answer (score 1):

No. Take this example $$P=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix},\quad A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $$A^TPA=\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{pmatrix}<P$$
but $$APA^T=\begin{pmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}\not\le P$$

Comment: Eigen values of A are both zero and do not lie on the unit circle as given by op.